# Neither was vs. Neither were

Tags: grammar

I saw this sentence in this article (https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2024/03/american-satellites-russia-ukraine-war/677775/):

*"Neither company **was** willing to say whether it had ever detected instances when it suspected that Russia had used its satellites, nor **was** either willing to describe how it ensured that its customers were not in fact Russian front companies."*

Because of neither, implying two companies, shouldn't the "was" become "were" in both cases?